# Oracle listener give "Message 850 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=NL"

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, listener

I'have just completed oracle 11g database software installation on Linux.
I launched `netca` and configured a `listener`.
As soon as I try to run `lsnrctl` I get the following error.

```
[oracle@lnx-db ~]$ lsnrctl

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 10-MAY-2019 15:34:41

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Message 850 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=NL
```

The environment variables seem to me set correctly.

```
[oracle@lnx-db ~]$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=


[oracle@lnx-db ~]$ echo $ORACLE_HOME $ORACLE_SID $ORACLE_BASE
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1 ORCL /u01/app/oracle
```

From what I read on https://community.oracle.com/thread/2322893?tstart=0 it could be a problem with the `mesg` but files seems there and readable.

```
[oracle@lnx-db ~]$ file $ORACLE_HOME/network/mesg/*
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/naukus.msb: data
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/naukus.msg: ASCII English text
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/ncrus.msb:  data
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/ncrus.msg:  ASCII English text
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/niqus.msb:  data
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/niqus.msg:  ASCII English text
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/nlus.msb:   data
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/nlus.msg:   ASCII English text
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/nmpus.msb:  data
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/nmpus.msg:  ASCII English text
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/nmrus.msb:  data
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/nmrus.msg:  ASCII English text
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/nnfus.msb:  data
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/nnfus.msg:  ASCII English text
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/nnlus.msg:  ASCII English text
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/snlus.msb:  data
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/snlus.msg:  ASCII English text
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/tnsus.msb:  data
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/mesg/tnsus.msg:  ASCII English text
```

Any hints?

EDIT1: As suggested below I've checked `NLS_LANG` and `TNS_ADMIN` variables. Both are not set. But settings them does not fix the problem:

```
[oracle@lnx-db u01]$ echo $NLS_LANG $TNS_ADMIN ; lsnrctl
American_America.UTF8 /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 10-MAY-2019 16:16:05

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Message 850 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=NL
LSNRCTL> q
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity why are you installing 11.2.0.1 which is already out of support?

Comment: @kevinsky I'd like to be able to tell you that it's for migration tests to a newer version but sadly it's a requirement

Comment: What's `NLS_LANG` set to? And `TNS_ADMIN` ? You can also try running `lsnrctl` under `strace` to see which files it's actually looking for (and failing to find)

Comment: Variables was `set`ted but not correctly `export`ed!

Comment: In over 20 years of working with Oracle, I have _never_ known this error to be anything other than an incorrect setting of ORACLE_HOME.  What you show for ORACLE_HOME looks reasonable, so the next thing I'd want to check is to make sure that it is correctly set _within the session_  from which you start 'lsnrctl'.  Please edit your op to clearly show these two command _within the same session_: 'env | grep ORA' and ' lsnrctl status'.